# Make /afk command accept numbers not letters in python

Tags: python, command, discord, discord.py

I want to make it that when someone does /AFK and writes letters instead of numbers, it should show something like "input numbers not letters". Here is my code:

````
async def afk(ctx, mins : int):
    current_nick = ctx.author.nick
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} has gone afk for {mins} minutes.", delete_after=5)
    await ctx.author.edit(nick=f"[AFK]{ctx.author.name}")

    counter = 0
    while counter <= int(mins):
        counter += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

        if counter == int(mins):
            await ctx.author.edit(nick=current_nick)
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} is no longer AFK", delete_after=5)
            break```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the typehint and then use try/except

```py
async def afk(ctx, mins):
    try:
        mins = int(mins)
    except ValueError:
        return await ctx.send("input numbers not letters")
    # your other code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
async def afk(ctx, mins : int):
    try:
        mins = int(mins)
    except ValueError:
        # ...
        # <send the message here.>
        # ...
        return

    current_nick = ctx.author.nick
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} has gone afk for {mins} minutes.", delete_after=5)
    await ctx.author.edit(nick=f"[AFK]{ctx.author.name}")

    asyncio.sleep(60 * mins)

    await ctx.author.edit(nick=current_nick)
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} is no longer AFK", delete_after=5)
```

Here, we try to convert mins to an int, and if it fails, send the message. Otherwise, continue as usual. I think you can also remove the while loop and if statement like I did here.

Comment: it didn't work, with my code it used to show like "someone went afk for bruh moments" if they did /afk bruh, but with your code it doesn't send any message for some reason. How do I send a message? I did ```await ctx.send('Please use numbers.')``` is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Generally I agree with [@Poojan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65590777/13158153), but there's a much simpler way than try/except:

```
async def afk(ctx, mins):
    if not mins.isdigit():
        return await ctx.send("input numbers not letters")
    mins = int(mins)
```